# Trigger Asp.net CalendarExtender on textbox focus

Tags: asp.net, textbox, onfocus, calendarextender

CalendarExtender fires on target click event. So if you need to open calendar extender when textbox get focus (like with TAB key) it wont work just by itself.

```
<asp:textbox id="textBoxId" runat="server" />
<asp:RangeValidator id="valDatumRG" ControlToValidate="textBoxId" Type="Date" ... ValidationGroup="valGr" Display="dynamic" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="cldExtTermin" runat="server" TargetControlID="textBoxId" PopupButtonID="textBoxId" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `PopupButtonID` property from the `CalendarExtender` control

Comment: LOL.It's certainly the easiest way. Who would say that papup control isnt required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add methods that will trigger click events when texbox get focus, or lost.

```
 textBoxId.Attributes.Add("onblur", "ValidatorOnChange(event);") 
 textBoxId.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.click();")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the CalendarExtender on both Popup button click and Textbox focus. Try the following line of code to show the calendar on both Textbox and Image click.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" onclick="showCalendar();" onfocusout="showCalendar();" ID="txtDate" />
    <asp:ImageButton runat="Server" ID="imgPopup" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" CssClass="MyCalendar" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" />
```

and add a javascript function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showCalendar() {
       $( "#<%=imgPopup.ClientID %>" ).trigger( "click" ); //I've used .ClientID here just in case your page is inherited from a Master page
    }
    </script>
```

That should display the calendar when  you click on the Textbox, and the calendar will be hidden once you click anywhere else on the form